# strange NSString behaviour when used with [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a weird one for you guys today, I think my NSStrings are incorrectly encoded.

```
NSString * convertedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mesh->groupMesh[i].materialData->textureName];
```

-textureName is just a c style string that I'm converting into an NSString.

-The string is: "dennum1.png"

```
NSArray * line = [convertedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSString * texPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:line[0] ofType:line[1]];
```

I then split it into an NSArray line, separated by periods "."

This makes it so that line[0] is dennum1, and line[1] is png.

I even do an NSLog to make sure:

```
NSLog(@"Name:%@ Type:%@", line[0], line[1]);

2013-09-21 02:15:27.386 SteveZissou[8846:c07] Name:dennum1 Type:png
```

I parse this over to the pathForResource function and I get a (null) response.

BUT if I hard type the file name into the code I.E:

```
    convertedString = @"dennum1.png";

    NSArray * line = [convertedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    NSString * texPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:line[0] ofType:line[1]];

    NSLog(@"This is the texPath: %@",texPath);
```

IT WORKS?!

```
This is the texPath: /Users/meow/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/2DEB8076-5F9D-45DE-8A73-10B1C8A084B4/SteveZissou.app/dennum1.png
```

Is it possible that the NSString that I hard type in the code and the NSString that comes from the conversion are encoded differently?

When I NSLog them individually I get the same result regardless of type:

```
2013-09-21 02:15:27.386 SteveZissou[8846:c07] This is the c style string: dennum1.png
2013-09-21 02:15:27.386 SteveZissou[8846:c07] This is the converted c style string: dennum1.png
2013-09-21 02:15:27.386 SteveZissou[8846:c07] This is the string manually typed in: dennum1.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after HOURS of skimming through possible code combinations and found it by accident.

I used NSURL functions to get the path based on the strings I was using, which resulted in this path:

```
file://localhost/Users/meow/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/2DEB8076-5F9D-45DE-8A73-10B1C8A084B4/SteveZissou.app/dennum2.png%0D
```

Look at the very end! That's not supposed to be there! Turns out it's called a carriage return and it was pulled with the file (probably a remnant of the files formatting), but invisible to NSLog, however it wasn't invisible to NSURL (NSURL must read the bytes and display what they are?). So snipping the carriage return off the end of the path gave me the correct file and everything is OK.

I kept thinking to myself to use a hex editor to look at the file, but couldn't find one on the mac appstore free, I think if this was windows I would've caught it in half the time.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use the methods in NSPathUtilities that are designed to handle this stuff. Like:

```
NSString * texPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:string.stringByDeletingPathExtension ofType:string.pathExtension];
```

Also, there's `-fileSystemRepresentation` which will convert an NSString to a `const char *` and throw an exception if the string can't be converted correctly.

Comment: I did those two things and still got the same result.

Comment: That is definitely weird... What does the string return for `-fastestEncoding`?

Comment: I got 30 for both UTF8 and FileSystemRep, what does this mean?